# Unable to get response in google app engine

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

Hi I have to deploy a servlet in google app engine.But unable to get response in the following code.I am not even getting error in logs.Following is the piece of code.

```
String executeHttpRequest(String jsonData,  HttpPost httpPost,HttpServletResponse resp)  throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException
{
     resp.getWriter().println("inside execute http req1");
    HttpResponse response=null;
    String line = "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    resp.getWriter().println("inside execute http req2");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonData));
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    resp.getWriter().println("inside execute http req3");

    response = client.execute(httpPost);

    resp.getWriter().println("inside execute http req4");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){ result.append(line); }
    resp.getWriter().println("inside execute http req5");
    resp.getWriter().println(result.toString());
    String resultstring=result.toString();
    return resultstring;
}
```

In this code,I am not getting response at

```
 response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Till there everything is going fine.But main point is need to get response   from webservice.
Firstly I have executed it in jetty server.It is working fine.Then I have deployed in google app engine.

Comment: maybe security issue, you need to add key in the header, take a look in your google developer console. https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158857

Comment: Ya thank you.By using oauth login process my problem is solved